# File.OpenRead return string valueI

Tags: c#

I need to return string from method GetLogFolder(string fileName) so I can pass the string to GenerateStreamFromString(string value) that I need to use for DataContractJsonSerializer. Can you please advise?

```
     public Stream GetLogFolder(string fileName)
            {
                var documents = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "log", fileName);
    
                 return File.OpenRead(documents);
    
            }

private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
        {
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
        }
```

I want that because the method

```
private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
        {
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
        }

    public T GetObject<T>(string json)
            {
                var knownType = new List<Type> { typeof(JsonLogEvent) };
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(
                typeof(JsonLogEvent),
                new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK")
                });
    
                using (var stream = _localStorage.GetLogFolderMemoryStream(json))
                {
                    return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                }
            }
accepts string
```

Comment: GetLogFolder already is a stream. Why do you want to convert it to text and then back to a Stream? Anyway, if the files are just text, you can `File.ReadAllText()`

Comment: Hello, I edited my question

Comment: That doesn't help because I don't know which method you actually meant by `GetLogFolderMemoryStream`. However, there are much easier ways to deserialize json. Assuming you are not using .NET Core or 5 because of the use of DataContractSerializer, I suggest you [look at this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)

Comment: Your 2 examples don't share a single method. As Crowcoder already pointed out, your method GetLog**Folder** returns a stream, I'd expect a folder path. You need to read the data you need from that `FileStream` provided by `File.OpenRead`.

Comment: @Crowcoder thank zou, but I have namespace in the json and seems that is an issue with json. I tried your suggested approach but that threw an exception that there is a " .  "

Comment: OK, then just `File.ReadAllText()` and pass that string to your method.

Comment: ok, thank you. I have tried that now I get an exception about date time "String was not recognized as valid date time"

Comment: Well that is a different problem and without your json I have no idea. Sounds like your DateTimeFormat serializer setting is wrong or your data is bad.